# Add deleted timeline entry for answers that were deleted due to question deletion

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers, timeline

See this timeline [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52599286/timeline):

[image]

Right now, there is no current way to tell that this post was deleted. Can we add another entry in here, to show that this answer was deleted on Oct 3 at 21:19 when the question was deleted?

My use case: Currently [writing a bot](https://stackapps.com/questions/8091) to help try and detect possible bad reviews by users, for the mods. Right now, it's not possible to detect question deletion, without re-querying the question.

Comment: Any particular reason why we'd need to add deletion history events for every single answer under the question? I can't think of any situations where this would be a useful thing to do. What led you to wanting this information there?

Comment: @animuson Well, the timeline should be all the events for that post. If the question was deleted, and as a result all the answers were deleted, why shouldn't this be included in the history? My use case: Currently [writing a bot](https://stackapps.com/questions/8091) to help try and detect possible bad reviews by users, for the mods. I'm currently hanging out in the [workshop](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167908) room. Right now, it would be nice to detect answer deletion, without re-querying the question. [More info here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317432/295637).

Comment: I would edit that information into the question. Without context for why it's important, this request will be seen as a "just because" and almost certainly be declined.