# How to report bad reviewers

Tags: support, review, flags

I found a bad review and wondered if it should be flagged.

Luckily someone already asked [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317341/should-1-off-bad-reports-in-first-post-late-post-queue-be-reported). The answer is **yes**, bad reviewers should be flagged.

In my quest to figure out how to flag said review, I found [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76172/316262) which states that we should flag behaviour, but I couldn't find a flag button on the review page (and none exists on the user pages).

How do I flag an individual review?

---

I am asking because of the reject on [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27124063). I think the proposed edit took a carelessly written question and with a lot of effort turned it into a good one. One of the very few really good edits. But even if it turns out to not be flag worthy, my question still stands

Comment: Neuron, you might be interested in this announcement: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351117/282094

Comment: Other than removing thanks, that edit is no improvement.

Comment: @philipxy So what about "(btw I created an account just to ask this lol)"?

Comment: Yes, the thanks etc. But only removing social noise is not a good edit for editors requiring reviews.

Comment: @philipxy first of all, I find that last bit alone worthy of an edit. but apart from that the question doesn't have a clear wording. An example for that: "and I don't know if they should stay like that".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To bring moderator attention to an action that doesn't have an attached flag button, please raise a custom moderator flag on any of the user's posts and detail the problem, including links when applicable.

Comment: well, that's awkward. but thanks for clarifying!

Comment: No problem - can't expect everyone to know everything immediately. ;)

Comment: I meant the way of flagging behaviour is awkward.. '^^ reporting some random post for something else..

Comment: @Neuron Ideally, there would be a "flag review" button in every review action. But it requires lots of development time, and the gain isn't that big: what this answer suggest achieves the exact same goal, even if less elegant. Something like that [was already suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223947/can-we-have-a-system-to-submit-potential-robo-reviewers-for-moderators-attention) few years ago and is pending, i.e. not declined. If sometimes in the far future SE will have free time for its developers, they might do it. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask well, the two actions may ultimately have the same effect, but from a user perspective it is very confusing. There are surly many users in a similar position as I was in and who won't go the extra length and look through old stackexchange sites to see if reviews should be reported and if so; **how**. But of course, in the grand scheme of things I don't know what other dev tickets are open and how they compare in significance ;)

Comment: @Neuron [this is the list of open "tickets" that SE dev team is working on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-review). Enough for few years, with their current task force. :)